# React: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, calendar

I'm using React and rendering a Calender (@sentisso/react-modern-calendar-datepicker) which can select a range of date.

I've a button. When I click this, I update the state of that button and if it is true, the datepicker will show. if it is false, I hide the datepicker using conditional rendering.

```
const [selectedDayRange, setSelectedDayRange] = useState({
    from: null,
    to: null  
});

return (
<>
    <input type="button" onClick={() => toggleDateRangeVisible()} />
    {isDateRangeVisible && 
        <Calendar
          value={selectedDayRange}
          onChange={setSelectedDayRange}
          shouldHighlightWeekends
        />
    }
</>
)
```

When I click the button, the datepicker is shown. but when I click it again to hide the datepicker, I got this error. (The state of the visible was changed)

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')

Call Stack
eval
node_modules/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/lib/index.js (1:19754)
safelyCallDestroy
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (22932:0)
commitHookEffectListUnmount
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23100:0)
commitPassiveUnmountInsideDeletedTreeOnFiber
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25098:0)
commitPassiveUnmountEffectsInsideOfDeletedTree_begin
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25048:0)
commitPassiveUnmountEffects_begin
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24956:0)
commitPassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24941:0)
flushPassiveEffectsImpl
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27038:0)
flushPassiveEffects
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26984:0)
commitRootImpl
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26935:0)
commitRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26682:0)
performSyncWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26117:0)
flushSyncCallbacks
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12042:0)
eval
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25651:0)
```

```
const toggleDateRangeVisible = () => setIsDateRangeVisible(!isDateRangeVisible);
```

Here is codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-shadow-x978yh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: might be an issue with React v17+. Try react v16 or the fix proposed in the comments here: https://github.com/Kiarash-Z/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/issues/286

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of the library with React v17. A contributor has created a fork to fix this. You could probably use that library for it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hassanmojab/react-modern-calendar-datepicker

Github Thread: https://github.com/hassanmojab/react-modern-calendar-datepicker

Answer (score 2):

There is a temporary package availabe, as suggested in the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Kiarash-Z/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/issues/204#issuecomment-757520714):

You can download and install it using:

```
npm install --save @hassanmojab/react-modern-calendar-datepicker
```

Then change all the imports to:

```
import '@hassanmojab/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/lib/DatePicker.css';
import DatePicker from '@hassanmojab/react-modern-calendar-datepicker';
```

This is a temporary package as a solution just for this issue and won't be developed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date picker alternatives like:

NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Github Link as an example: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I tried the library [@sentisso/react-modern-calendar-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentisso/react-modern-calendar-datepicker) in my project and this issue happened, in my case I use Next JS 13.1.6 with React 18.2.0. The case is:

> When I try to change the display of date picker component from none to block, it goes perfect
> but if the condition is reversed, from display block to none, it returns
> the error which cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null.

I believe it is related to the issue of the react framework, since it has been pointed 2 years ago here in [github repo of the React 17](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20080)

But, strange is that when I tried the same code with another date picker from [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) the problem is gone. You can switch between condition using react-datepicker without error.